# How to insert new line in the same cell

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a small suggestion as I am new to excel vba,

I like to update the some string in a particular cell(j,8) , where t is a string to be update ,t varies from 1 to 10 .

I like to update t value in "alt enter " in a specific cell

if the cell is already fill ,  I like to add new line

```
 destlastrow = bsmWS.Range("A" & bsmWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   'Checking the BSM/CMS/LDP/RCTA (Test Catalog)
        For j = 2 To destlastrow
            b = onlyDigits(bsmWS.Range("A" & j).value)


   If InStr(b, "T") Or InStr(b, "") = 0 Then ' Check if it Test case or Test case ID
    ' do something
    ElseIf InStr(b, "T") Or InStr(b, "D") Then
    'do something
        ElseIf InStr(b, "P") Or InStr(b, "D") Then
    'do something
    Else
            iComp = StrComp(A, b, vbBinaryCompare)


            Select Case iComp
            Case 0
                With tabWS
                Inc value
                    erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 3)).Copy .Range(.Cells(value, 8), .Cells(value, 9))
                    tabWS.Range("B" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                End With     'tabWS

            End Select
           t = tabWS.Cells(value, 8).value
             bsmWS.Cells(j, 8).value = t & vbCrLf
             Exit For

           End If

        Next j
```

Above is my snippet.  I want to update "t" value which I get it from another worksheet, want to update into another worksheet (j,8).

Can someone give a valuable suggestion , how to add new lines in (j,8)

More clarity:

If cell (5,8) has already a value 
cell (5,8) = "Already a string"

How can I add a new line in the same cell
dim t as string
t= "new line add"

How I can add t value in the next line to cell(5,8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a new line you can use vbNewLine instead of vbCrLf.

To add to the text already in the cell use you can do it like this
    bsmWS.Cells(j, 8).value = bsmWS.Cells(j, 8).value & vbNewLine & t

Comment: This will take the value currently in the cell, add a new line and then add the string t  - bsmWS.Cells(j, 8).value = bsmWS.Cells(j, 8).value & vbNewLine & t

Comment: this is what I searched